# What is the order of execution of jobs in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline with multiple jobs inside it, but I'm facing a dilemma. What is the order of execution of the jobs inside the pipeline? Is it the order from the script? The reason I'm interested is because I want JOB1 to run at the beginning of the pipeline and somewhere in the middle. However, when the pipeline is running JOB1 in the beginning for whatever reason it runs twice in succession. Is there a particular reason for that or am I missing something?

```
    pipeline {
    agent any;
    options {
        timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    stages {
        stage('All tests in parallel') 
        {
            parallel 
            {
                stage('JOB1') {
                    steps {

                        callJobByName("JOB1")
                    }
                }
                stage('JOB2') {
                    steps {
                        callJobByName("JOB2")
                    }
                }
                stage('JOB1') {
                    steps {
                        callJobByName("JOB1")
                    }
                }
                stage('JOB3') {
                    steps {
                        callJobByName("JOB3")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the pipeline above, every `Stage` within the `parallel` block will run in parallel. So you can't guarantee an order. If you want to execute them in order, remove the parallel block. Then the `Stages` will execute in the order they are defined. If you just want to `JOB1` to execute first and then to execute others and JOB1 again in parallel, you can simply move the first stage out from the parallel block.

```
pipeline {
agent any;
options {
    timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
}
stages {
    stage('All tests in parallel') 
    {
        stage('JOB1') {
          steps {

              callJobByName("JOB1")
          }
        }
        parallel 
        {
            stage('JOB2') {
                steps {
                    callJobByName("JOB2")
                }
            }
            stage('JOB1') {
                steps {
                    callJobByName("JOB1")
                }
            }
            stage('JOB3') {
                steps {
                    callJobByName("JOB3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @SilviuSabău This depends on the logic you have in `callJobByName()`, in this method if you are not waiting until the Job is completed what will happen is, the parent Pipeline will schedule the JOB1 for you and return, it will not wait for it to finish, so all the Jobs will be scheduled within a short period of time which may look like it's happening in parallel.

Comment: There is nothing special there. I just echo the the build status and call the jobs on a specific branch within the project.

Comment: But I find it extremly strange that even move out JOB1 from the parallel block and add it again inside, JOB1 will execute as soon as the parallel block starts even if it's somewhere in the middle. I don't understand

Comment: Alternatively is there a way to pause everything in the parallel block, execute JOB1 after a certain amount of time has passed, let's say 45 minutes, and then resume the block?